# How to disable the minicart popup function completely in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

What would be the best method to disable the minicart popup/hover function completely without interrupting the ajax functions that are included?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same question as well.

Comment: @Ree see the below answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The feature to disable the popup is actually built into Magento2. To disable, go to `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart Sidebar` and change "Display Shopping Cart Sidebar" to No.

Comment: man you have saved the day!

Comment: thanks . I was searching for the reverse of it :)

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman , is it possible to make using layout or programmatically

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman, because once we disable this setting related value(checkout/sidebar/display) is storing in core_config_data table

Comment: @HiteshBalpande Not entirely sure what you mean, I have seen others just hide it via css if your wanting to keep certain parts of its functionality.